# Probability of picking 2 red and 2 blue marbles from a bag of 5 red and 5 blue

Tags: probability

You pick 4 marbles from a bag of 5 red and 5 blue, with no replacement. What is the probability of getting exactly 2 marbles of each color?

I think it's either 3/8 or 10/21 but I'm not sure which.

Comment: Draw a tree diagram, it will help you visualize the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I like to add another perspective to this as well. If we instead didn't care about the order. For example, RRBB and RBRB are indistinguishable. So what are the number of possible 4 marbles I can get? It can be all blue, all red, or in between. It is

\begin{align*} {10 \choose 4} \end{align*}

Now, we want to know how many ways I can get $2$ Red marbles with no regards to ordering. It is

\begin{align*} {5 \choose 2} \end{align*}

Same thing goes for the blue marbles as well. So ${5 \choose 2}{5 \choose 2}$ gives you the number of $2$ red and $2$ blue marbles you can get without worrying about ordering. So the answer is

\begin{align*} \frac{{5 \choose 2}{5 \choose 2}}{10 \choose 4} \end{align*}

Answer (score 3):

In simple cases, it is easy to visualize picking up balls by drawing a tree diagram. I'll skip that part.

To pick a red marble first, you have a probability $\frac{5}{10}$.
To pick another red marble, now you will have probability $\frac{4}{9}$ (since no replacement).

To pick a blue marble next, you have probability $\frac{5}{8}$, and for another $\frac{4}{7}$.

Note that this is not the only way to pick up the required balls, you can have other arrangements as
$RRBB,RBRB,BRBR,BBRR,BRRB,RBBR$, in total $\binom{4}{2}=6$ ways.

So your final probablity is $$6.\frac{5}{10}.\frac{4}{9}.\frac{5}{8}.\frac{4}{7}$$

Comment: So it seems that 10/21 was correct after all. Thank you

Comment: It seems the downvoter didn't like the answer. Well, the main thing is that you learnt something from this answer :)

Comment: I got the 10/21 one way and the 3/8 another way. The 3/8 way was faulty, though, because I tried to treat it as a Bernoulli problem even though there is no replacement and therefore bernoulli doesn't work because each trial doesn't maintain the same probablities

Comment: Perhaps it is worth mentioning that if the colors alternate, we obtain $$\frac{5}{10} \cdot \frac{5}{9} \cdot \frac{4}{8} \cdot \frac{4}{7}$$ and that this expression is equal to $$\frac{5}{10} \cdot \frac{4}{9} \cdot \frac{5}{8} \cdot \frac{4}{7}$$ which is why each of the six permutations has an equal probability of occurring.